# How to create a simple menu for a Java Snake Game?

Tags: java, menu, state

I want to add a simple menu to my Java Snake game which will contain three buttons (New Game, Difficulty and Quit). I have created a class for the menu and a class for the mouse input. I have used an enum to store the states of the game (MAIN_MENU, DIFFICULTY_MENU and GAME) and a variable called STATE which stores the current state.

The main problem is that although the state of the game is changed when the "New Game" button is pressed the game doesn't start. I have tried to add game state checks inside the methods that are involved in setting the gameplay and I have also tried calling those methods from the mousePressed() method of the MouseInput class but none of these worked.

I would greatly appreciate if you could give me some tips on how to solve this issue.
Here's my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;


    public class SnakeGame extends JFrame{

        public SnakeGame() {
            initGUI();
        }

        public void initGUI() {
            add(new GamePlay());
            setResizable(false);
            pack();

            setTitle("The Snake");
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->  {
            JFrame frame = new SnakeGame();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            }); 
        }


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GamePlay extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    private final int TOTAL_DOTS = 3600;
    private final int DOT_SIZE = 10;
    private final int RAND_POSITION = 29;
    //private final int DELAY = 140;


    private final int[] X = new int[TOTAL_DOTS];// the dots on X axis
    private final int[] Y = new int[TOTAL_DOTS];//the dots on Y axis

    private int dots;
    private int apple_X;
    private int apple_Y;
    private int score = 0;
    private int DELAY = 140;

    private boolean leftDirection = false;
    private boolean rightDirection = true;
    private boolean upDirection = false;
    private boolean downDirection = false;
    private boolean inGame = true;

    private Timer timer;
    private Image bodyPart;
    private Image snakeHead;
    private Image apple;

    private Menu menu;
    public static GameState STATE = GameState.MAIN_MENU;//current game state(it changes when menu buttons are pressed)


    public static enum GameState{
        MAIN_MENU,
        DIFFICULTY_MENU,
        GAME

    }

    public GamePlay() {

        setGamePlay();

    }


    public void setGamePlay() {

        addKeyListener(new KeyboardEvent());
        addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        if(STATE == GameState.GAME) {
        loadImages();
        startGame();

        } 
    }

    private void loadImages() {

        ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("src/images/dot.png");
        bodyPart = img2.getImage();

        ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("src/images/head.png");
        snakeHead = img1.getImage();

        ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon("src/images/apple.png");
        apple = img3.getImage();

    }

    //setting the starting snake length and the apple position on the board
    public void startGame() {
        dots = 3;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < dots; i++) {
            X[i] = 50 - i * 10;
            Y[i] = 50;
          }

        locateApple();

        timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        //timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(STATE == GameState.GAME) {

        draw(g);

        }else if(STATE == GameState.MAIN_MENU) {

            new Menu().displayMainMenu(g);

        }else if(STATE == GameState.DIFFICULTY_MENU) {

            new Menu().displayDifficultyMenu(g);
        }
        System.out.println("End of paint component method");
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        scoreDisplay(g);

        if(inGame) {
            g.drawImage(apple, apple_X, apple_Y,this);


            for(int i = 0 ; i < dots; i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    g.drawImage(snakeHead,X[i], Y[i], this);
                }else {
                    g.drawImage(bodyPart, X[i], Y[i], this);
                }
            }

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

        }else {

            gameOver(g);
        }

    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        String msg = "Game Over!";
        String msg2 = "Score: " + score + " " + "Length: " + dots;
        Font small = new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,14 );
        FontMetrics messageSize = getFontMetrics(small);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(small);
        g.drawString(msg, (WIDTH - messageSize.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, HEIGHT / 2);

        g.drawString(msg2, (WIDTH - messageSize.stringWidth(msg2)) / 2, (HEIGHT / 2) + 20);

        restartMessageDisplay(g);
    }


    public void scoreDisplay(Graphics g) {
        String gameScore = "Score: " + score;
        String snakeLength = "Snake length: " + dots;
        Font small = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(small);
        g.drawString(gameScore,480, 20);
        g.drawString(snakeLength, 480, 40);

    }


    public void restartMessageDisplay(Graphics g) {
        String restartMessage = " Press Enter to restart";
        Font small = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(small); 
        g.drawString(restartMessage, (WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(restartMessage)) / 2, (HEIGHT / 2) + 40);

    }


    private void checkApple() {

        if((X[0] == apple_X) && (Y[0] == apple_Y)) {
            dots++;

            locateApple();

            score += 5;//score update
            DELAY -= 5;// speed increase when snake eats the apple


            if(DELAY >= 40) {
                timer.setDelay(DELAY);
            }   
        }       
    }

    //snake move logic
    private void move() {

        for(int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
            X[i] = X[(i-1)];
            Y[i] = Y[(i-1)];
        }

        if(leftDirection) {
            X[0] -= DOT_SIZE;  
        }

        if(rightDirection) {
            X[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if(upDirection) {
            Y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;               
        }

        if(downDirection) {
            Y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }
    }
        //checking for collision with the walls or the snake itself
        private void checkCollision() {

         for(int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {

             if((i > 4) && (X[0] == X[i]) && (Y[0] == Y[i])) {
                 inGame = false;
             }
         }


         if(X[0] < 0) {
             inGame = false;
         }

         if(X[0] > WIDTH) {
             inGame = false;
         }

         if(Y[0] < 0) {
             inGame = false;
         }

         if(Y[0] > HEIGHT) {
             inGame = false;
         }

         if(!inGame) {
             timer.stop();
         }

        }


        //setting apple position on the board
        public void locateApple() {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POSITION);
            apple_X = random * DOT_SIZE;

            random = (int) (Math.random()* RAND_POSITION);
            apple_Y = random * DOT_SIZE;


        }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(inGame) {

            checkApple();
            checkCollision();
            move();

        }

        repaint();

    }

    private class KeyboardEvent extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!rightDirection)) {
                leftDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
            }

            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!leftDirection)) {
                rightDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;

            }

            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!downDirection)) {
                upDirection = true;
                leftDirection = false;
                rightDirection = false;
            }

            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!upDirection)) {
                downDirection = true;
                leftDirection = false;
                rightDirection = false;

            }


            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE) {
                timer.stop();
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                timer.start();
            }

            //game restart
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

             if(!inGame) {
                inGame = true;
                leftDirection = false;
                rightDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
                score = 0;
                DELAY = 140;
                setGamePlay();
                repaint();

              }
           }
        } 
    }
}


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu {
    public Rectangle newGameButton;
    public Rectangle gameDifficultyButton;
    public Rectangle quitButton;
    public Rectangle easyDifficultyButton;
    public Rectangle mediumDifficultyButton;
    public Rectangle hardDifficultyButton;
    public Button button1;

    public Menu() {
        int buttonWidth = 150;
        int buttonHeight = 50;

        newGameButton = new Rectangle((GamePlay.WIDTH - buttonWidth) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) - 50, buttonWidth, buttonHeight); 
        gameDifficultyButton = new Rectangle((GamePlay.WIDTH - buttonWidth) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) + 50, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        quitButton = new Rectangle((GamePlay.WIDTH - buttonWidth) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) + 150, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        easyDifficultyButton = new Rectangle((GamePlay.WIDTH - buttonWidth) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) - 50, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        mediumDifficultyButton = new Rectangle((GamePlay.WIDTH - buttonWidth) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) + 50, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        hardDifficultyButton = new Rectangle((GamePlay.WIDTH - buttonWidth) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) + 150, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        }


    public void displayMainMenu(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D  buttonGraphics =(Graphics2D) g;

        String title = "THE SNAKE GAME";
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50);
        FontMetrics size = g.getFontMetrics(font);

        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(title,(GamePlay.WIDTH-size.stringWidth(title)) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) - 130);


        Font buttonFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28);
        g.setFont(buttonFont);

        g.drawString("New Game",newGameButton.x + 2, newGameButton.y + 35);
        buttonGraphics.draw(newGameButton);

        g.drawString("Difficulty",gameDifficultyButton.x + 15,gameDifficultyButton.y + 35);
        buttonGraphics.draw(gameDifficultyButton);

        g.drawString("Quit", quitButton.x + 45, quitButton.y + 35);
        buttonGraphics.draw(quitButton);    
    }   


    public void displayDifficultyMenu(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D difficultyMenuGraphics = (Graphics2D) g;

        String title = "Difficulty level";
        Font difficultyMenuTitleFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,40);
        FontMetrics size = g.getFontMetrics(difficultyMenuTitleFont);

        g.setFont(difficultyMenuTitleFont);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(title, (GamePlay.WIDTH - size.stringWidth(title)) / 2, (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) - 100);

        Font difficultyButtonFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28);
        g.setFont(difficultyButtonFont);

        g.drawString("Easy", easyDifficultyButton.x + 40 , easyDifficultyButton.y + 35);
        difficultyMenuGraphics.draw(easyDifficultyButton);

        g.drawString("Medium",mediumDifficultyButton.x + 20, mediumDifficultyButton.y + 35);
        difficultyMenuGraphics.draw(mediumDifficultyButton);

        g.drawString("Hard", hardDifficultyButton.x + 40, hardDifficultyButton.y + 35);
        difficultyMenuGraphics.draw(hardDifficultyButton);
    }   
}


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.lang.Thread.State;


public class MouseInput extends MouseAdapter {
    public Rectangle newGameButton;
    public Rectangle gameDifficultyButton;
    public Rectangle quitButton;
    public Rectangle easyDifficultyButton;
    public Rectangle mediumDifficultyButton;
    public Rectangle hardDifficultyButton;
    Graphics g;


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();


        //NewGame button
        if(mouseX >= (GamePlay.WIDTH - 150) / 2 && mouseX <=  ((GamePlay.WIDTH - 150) / 2) + 150) {
            if(mouseY >= (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) - 50  && mouseY <= (GamePlay.HEIGHT/ 2)) {
                GamePlay.STATE = GamePlay.GameState.GAME;
                System.out.println(GamePlay.STATE);

          }
         }

        //Difficulty button
        if(mouseX >= (GamePlay.WIDTH - 150) / 2 && mouseX <= ((GamePlay.WIDTH - 150)/ 2 ) + 150) {
            if(mouseY >= (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) + 50  && mouseY <= (GamePlay.HEIGHT/ 2) + 100) {
                GamePlay.STATE = GamePlay.STATE.DIFFICULTY_MENU;
                System.out.println("Game state = " + GamePlay.STATE)
          }
        }

        //Quit button
        if(mouseX >= (GamePlay.WIDTH - 150) / 2 && mouseX <= ((GamePlay.WIDTH - 150)/ 2 ) + 150) {
            if(mouseY >= (GamePlay.HEIGHT / 2) + 150  && mouseY <= (GamePlay.HEIGHT/ 2) + 200) { 

                System.exit(0);

          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to read about java naming conventions. UPPERCASE implies constants, an STATE obviously cant be constant. Writing such code is highly confusing for experienced java folks. Beyond that: do I see that right, that you are *drawing* your menus yourself? You know that Swing has pre-build classes for that? So unless you really want to everything from scratch, the real answer would be: read how bilt in java swing menus work.

Comment: I never intended to make the variable state a constant(it was a simple mistake). Regarding the menu, I would like to place it on the center of the screen but I see that most of the swing menu examples are placed on the top of the window. Could I use normal buttons and add them to the  JFrame and then create actionListeners to record the mouse clicks?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to try. Typically menus sit on the top of your windows. So yes, when you want your elements more centered, using some buttons would be a good idea.

Comment: I have created the buttons in the meantime and added an action listener for the "Start Game" button but it still doesn't work. It is still unclear for me which is the code that should be inserted inside the actionPerformed method of the listener in order to trigger the start of the game (as I said before I tried calling different methods inside GamePlay class with no success). Since the menu buttons were added to the frame, should I clear the content of it before starting the game itself?

Comment: Any ideas on why the game doesn't start when the "New Game" button is pressed although I called the exact same methods that are used to start the game(which by the way work perfectly) when there is no menu?